# Kerberos authentication for Pyspark in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, kerberos

I'm trying to use a python Jupyter Notebook and pyspark to access data. The data requires kerberos authentication. I can achieve this just fine in terminal:

```
(base) [<user>]$ kinit
Password for user: 
(base) [<user>]$ pyspark
...
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
      /_/

Using Python version 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022 06:56:58)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> df1 = spark.read.parquet("<link to parquet")
>>>
```

And I can show it with no issues. But when I try to follow a similar process in a notebook, I run into problems with authentication

I've attempted to replicate the terminal commands in a notebook:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
!kinit <<<'<pw>'
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SparkJupyterTest").getOrCreate()
# everything works up through here. Binds correctly
df1 = spark.read.parquet("<link to parquet>") #here's where the error occurs
... WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: ...
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

I've tried different levels of master. My understanding is I need to authorize with my kerberos key. I gave it the password already though using terminal command `!kinit <<<'<pw>'`, and I know it took because I can do as follows and recieve dates/times where I've filled in x's indicating I've authenticated (I thought..):

```py
!klist
Ticket cache: xxxx
Default principal: <user>

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
xxx                  xxxx                          xxx
    renew until xxxx
```

Any advice on this error? Am I wrong in assuming it's related to kerberos authentication? Am I authenticating incorrectly for a notebook? I don't have a keytab file, I use manual input as of now. Thanks!

Comment: The pyspark terminal and jupyter should use the exact same Spark config. How are you running jupyter? After running kinit?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, I start a new notebook and type what I included in the code block (import pyspark, etc.) . So I use the kinit command to authenticate. I thought that would be enough too but the error implies it isn't and that I haven't authenticated

Comment: Did you run kinit before starting the notebook server, rather than in a code cell?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I've tried with both, running kinit in terminal and in code. The klist command shows I should be authenticated too